# telerik NuGet integration

Tags: telerik, nexus

I'm trying to integrate Telerik's NuGet repo on my local nexus repository (v. 3.2.0.01). 
I've found this on the web, http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/nuget-install but so far no libraries are shown.

I created a new proxy type NuGet repo with the following:
url: https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget
checked the HTTP Authentication
type: username
and provided  a valid username and password.

Don't see any errors. but don't see any assets either.

has anyone successfully integrated Telerik's NuGet with Nexus OSS?

thanks,